# rails 3.x, mongoid and scoped sorting without help of database query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, sorting, scope, mongoid

I have a Rails 3.2.x app with mongo and mongoid.
I want to have a 'scope' defined in my model that would sort my 'users' by name.
The catch is that the sort should be case **insensitive** which is not supported by mongo itself.

Is there a way to do it correctly using scopes?

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic case calling for a persisted calculated field pattern.

Say the field you want to sort on is called `name`. In your model, trap assignments to `name` and set an additional field you can query. For example:

```
def name=(value)
    self['name'] = value
    self['_lc_name'] = value.downcase
end
```

You don't need to define the calculated field as a Mongoid field.

Create an index on `_lc_name` for faster sorting using `index` in Mongoid.

Comment: Sim, are you suggesting I keep ```_lc_name``` in the database and create a scope on it?

Comment: Yes, that's what the persisted calculated field pattern is about: you are caching the result of a calculation (`downcase`) and feeding it to the standard sort operation. The pattern became popular with relational databases because SQL has a very limited set of operations and calculating a new field value on the fly would sometimes be too expensive.

Comment: Well MySQL for example has a built in ```toLower``` function I think. It is just mongodb that lacks it. This is definitely not the solution I was looking for, more of a workaround. But I'll accept it if I don't find pure Rails/Mongoid solution.

Comment: If you were querying, you could do lowercase comparisons using regular expressions. However, for sorting, there is no native Mongo solution. You may be able to extend Mongoid to get the functionality you need. You would need to do three things most likely: (1) create a new criterion, e.g., `case_insensitive_order_by` (see `Mongoid::Criterion::Optional#order_by`), (2) store information in `Context` about the fact that you need to post process the Mongo cursor before sending it to client code and (3) decorate at a minimum `Mongoid::Criteria#each` to apply the post-processing when necessary.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the [mongodb aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) to achieve this.

A quick summary would be that you can do a pipe like command to achieve this (like in unix).  You can do 'n' of operations using the aggregation framework.

Comment: Aggregation Framework in fact has a ```toLower``` function defined. I'm still puzzled how to use it with Rails/Mongoid though.

Comment: I would not advise using the aggregation framework for two reasons. First, my understanding is that internally it uses Mongo M/R, which is implemented in JS. Mongo M/R can be very useful but it is also slow, hard to debug and can crash the entire server. We use Mongo M/R extensively in production so I speak from experience. Second, M/R creates a cached, i.e., stale, view of your data. That's not what you want. M/R is overkill for your needs. See my answer below.